# How to use JAXB autoInheritance for generated classes from WSDL?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, xjc, cxf-xjc-plugin

I'm generating java classes from `soap` webservices `wsdl`.

The requests do not share a common interface, but I'd like them to implement one, or extend a common class.

Therefore I'm trying to use the `xcj-plugin`. The statement

```
<extraarg>-xjc-XautoInheritance-xmlRootElementsImplement=com.path.to.BaseInterface</extraarg>
```

should take care of this, and let all `@XmlRootElement` annotated classes automatically implement the defined `BaseInterface`.

But the generated classes are without that. No class is implementing this interface. Why? What might be wrong with the following configuration?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-xjc-XautoInheritance-xmlRootElementsExtend=com.path.to.BaseClass</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-xjc-XautoInheritance-xmlRootElementsImplement=com.path.to.BaseInterface</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>cxf</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-mark-generated</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.10-b140310.1920</version>
                </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.8.2</version>
                     </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.4-1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.10.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please try also adding `-xjc-XautoInheritance` to activate the plugin.

Comment: See also this for CXF usage: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Using+JAXB2+Basics+Plugins+with+CXF

Comment: Test project: https://svn.java.net/svn/jaxb2-commons~svn/basics/trunk/tests/issues/

Comment: props to @lexicore, please add this as an answer, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `-xjc-XautoInheritance` to activate the plugin.

See [the following page](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Using+JAXB2+Basics+Plugins+with+CXF) for CXF usage of JAXB2 Basics plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlOptions>
            <wsdlOption>
                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/CustomerService.wsdl</wsdl>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/binding.xml</bindingFile>
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/binding.xjb</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
                <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>-xjc-XhashCode</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>-xjc-Xequals</extraarg>
                </extraargs>
            </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version><!-- version --></version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of JAXB2 Basics plugins.